# IOS: Connect my CustomTableController to UITableViewController create in storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitableview

As title, I have created a new class type `UITableViewController` name TableViewControllr and added in custom class storyboard. But when i run my projetc in simulator I see an empty controller. if i reset to `UITableViewController` in custom class I see all objects i had designed.

In the **TableViewController.h**:

```
@class TableViewController;

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController {

TableViewController *tableViewController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet TableViewController *tableViewController;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sensorLabel;
@end
```

Comment: In your TableViewController you have a property to a TableViewController?

Comment: you mean in interface builder?

Comment: No.. obviously in your code

Comment: no probably not. Sorry i'm new in ios development. Can you explain me what i have to add to the code?

Comment: Well to be honest.. if this really is your .m file then remove EVERY line of code that you postet here. This looks more like source of the .h file but even then most is wrong.

Comment: Don't implement any of the methods below when you use the static table view:

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}

Comment: You can implement them but then you have to know what you are doing ;)